# Свойство column-count не работает в Google Chrome

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome

В списке категорий в моём магазине мне нужно было отобразить список в несколько колонок,для этого я использовал:

```
-webkit-column-count:3;  
   -moz-column-count:3;  
        column-count:3;  
-webkit-column-width: 25%; 
   -moz-column-width: 25%;  
        column-width: 25%;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;  
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;  
        column-gap: 10px;
```

с шириной колонки, отступом и т.д. Проблема заключается в том, что на Chrome `column-count` не работает вообще. В Firefox и Opera всё отлично работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А версия какая?

Comment: и html добавляйте

Comment: Обновил до версии 59.0.3071.109, и заработало. Спасибо за подсказку))Но странно то что при этом не отображаются эти свойства в DevTools

Answer (score 1):

Советую сначала изучать совместимость с браузерами, если что-то у вас на одно браузере работает, а на другом нет.

Для `column-count` соместимость с браузерами можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp).
(поддерживается Chrome'ом с 50-ой версии с префиксом `-webkit-`)

Comment: понял, спасибо за совет